# Symfony connect to multiple DB host for failover scenario in AWS

Tags: symfony, database-connection, symfony-2.8

For the symfony application, we have the DB connectivity and parameters.yml as mentioned below :

```
parameters:
     database_host: db-service-01
     database_port: 3306
     database_name: sample
     database_user: dbuser
     database_password: dbpwd
```

This is working fine till we have one DB host. Now we have moved to AWS cloud and we have multiple DB host as db-service-01,db-service-02,db-service-03 to support DB failover for one of the host. So when we are starting the application and db-service-01 host is down, then it will connect to second host db-service-02 or when second host fails, it will connect to third host db-service-03 and vice-versa.
Now when I add this multiple DB host in the parameters.yml with comma separated, it's not working as it is expecting  a legal host name. Below is the snippet where only the host changes and rest remains the same.

```
parameters:
    database_host: db-service-01,db-service-02,db-service-03
    database_port: 3306
    database_name: sample
    database_user: dbuser
    database_password: dbpwd
```

I am aware on connecting to multiple DB with more than 1 connection but not sure on how do we get this failover scenario get working.

Any idea/suggestion/help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this is supported by Doctrine. You could use DNS Failover instead, see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover-configuring.html

Comment: @dbrumann thanks for suggestion, but was looking into DB and Doctrine. May be in later version of symfony it will be supported.

Comment: I think this is not so much an issue with Symfony, but Doctrine itself. You could create your own Connection Wrapper that supports this or maybe there is a community project for this already that I am not aware of. You could look at the [PrimaryReadReplicaConnection](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/4.0.x/src/Connections/PrimaryReadReplicaConnection.php) as a kind of reference for this

Answer (score 0):

After some analysis and searching I could not get any solution. There is no support of such feature from Doctrine itself. I tried another method to achieve this. I tried to follow the symfony structure as much as could. Below is my working solution.

I added parameters.php in my config folder with the parameters for DB connectivity and importing the files in the config.yml, this will overwrites the parameters.yml file.

In the parameters.php I am manually checking for all the DB host, whichever connecting first is set in the parameters. Also from the list of host, if first one doesn't connect then it checks for the second one and so on.

This worked for me. Thanks @dbrumann for the suggestion.